# From a 3.3v Pin do we separate Positive and Negative flow? If so, how?

Tags: voltage, batteries, raspberry-pi, electron

If we do not separate Positive and Negative flow, what is the flow from a 3.3V connection?

A Little more background on why I ask this question and my confusion follows

I have been reading simple circuit design tutorials online, most of these include a battery with two terminals, one positive and one negative, which we connect cables to and eventually complete a circuit.

However as I began to progress, I noticed certain circuits began to have a **3.3V** connection - One example would be a GPIO pin(*Pin #1*) on a **Raspberry Pi.**
If I was to make use of this pin, would this be a Positive or Negative terminal?
Perhaps it doesnt matter? or perhaps it is neither?

Answer (score 2):

The 3.3V connection on a RPi is +3.3 volts, relative to the Pi's Ground.  The Pi also has a +5V connection on the I/O header - this is +5V relative to the Pi's ground pins.

In general, any voltage you see mentioned on a circuit is the voltage relative to the circuit's ground.  And, in most cases, the term "ground" does not imply a connection to the earth - it is just the point in the circuit that we choose to call "Zero Volts", and use as a reference when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Since voltages are relative to ground, that would be positive. And ground (or power supply return) would be the negative part.

["What is ground and what does it do?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/what-is-ground-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: *"And ground (or power supply return) "* So if we connected a LED between the **3.3V** and the **Ground** temrminals, is this the same as doing so with a Battery and a LED? Is this a correct visualization?

Comment: Yes. Although we usually don't since there's a decent chance that this will burn out the LED.

Comment: So then also if we connected something to the **3.3V** terminal but not the **ground**, wouldnt this cause the circuit to not be complete and fail?(Like would be the case with a simple battery-to-led-to-battery circuit?

Comment: The ground connection is not the only way to complete the circuit, it is simply the most convenient. If we connect to a GPIO instead then we can control whether the circuit is complete or not by changing the output.

Comment: Actually, a correction. Since we can control the voltage from the GPIO, we can control whether or not current will flow. The circuit will always be complete regardless.